# ORM que possa conectar com 2 tipos de BD (SQL ou HANA)

Tags: sql, entity-framework, nhibernate, dapper

Alguma sugestão de algum ORM ou Micro ORM que possa conectar/manipular 2 tipos de banco de dados diferentes, não simultaneos?

O cenário: Já possuo uma aplicação que utiliza SQL, preciso adapta-lo para aceitar alem do SQL, o HANA que tambem utiliza PL-SQL, por tanto não teria problemas com as querys.

Alguma dica de um ORM ou Micro ORM, em eu possa setar em uma configuração o BD em questão (SQL ou HANA).

Comment: se não tem problema com a query user o dapper

Comment: o dapper suporta isso? em minhas pesquisas vi que usando FactoryMethod, implementado na classe DbProvidersFactories, pode se intancias qualquer classe que implementa a IDbConnection. Segue a referencia https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5898711/data-layer-abstract-factory, bem antiga! mas se tiver um exemplo de como faço isso com daaper seria de grande ajuda!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu tenho em uma aplicação WebAPI onde suporto SQL e MYSQL
A implementação é bem simples:

Criei uma classe Abstrata com a configuração das duas conexões
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue código:
https://gist.github.com/thiagoloureiro/7d8fab3eed2e5a6f8bb8639a0c65ff54

```
namespace Data.Dapper.Class
{
    public abstract class BaseRepository
    {
        public string connstringSQL = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SqlServerConnString"].ConnectionString;

        public MySqlConnection GetMySqlConnection(bool open = true,
            bool convertZeroDatetime = false, bool allowZeroDatetime = false)
        {
            string cs = "Server=xxx;Port=41890;Database=yyyy;Uid=zzz;Pwd=db;";
            var csb = new MySqlConnectionStringBuilder(cs)
            {
                AllowZeroDateTime = allowZeroDatetime,
                ConvertZeroDateTime = convertZeroDatetime
            };
            var conn = new MySqlConnection(csb.ConnectionString);
            if (open) conn.Open();
            return conn;
        }
    }
}
```

Aí no caso de MYSQL:

```
 using (var db = GetMySqlConnection())
{
    const string sql = @"insert into User (Login, Password, CreatedOn, LastLogon) values (@Login, @Password, NOW(), NOW())";

    db.Execute(sql, new { Login = username, Password = password }, commandType: CommandType.Text);
}
```

SQL Server:

```
using (var db = new SqlConnection(connstring))
{
    const string sql = @"insert into [User] ([Login], [Password], [CreatedOn], [LastLogon]) values (@Login, @Password, GETDATE(), GETDATE())";

    db.Execute(sql, new { Login = username, Password = password }, commandType: CommandType.Text);
}
```

Então na linha de comando do using eu diferencio qual DB quero usar.

No meu Github tenho algumas coisas onde utilizei esse código:

https://github.com/thiagoloureiro/WebAPIBase/

abs

Answer (score 0):

O NHibernate é multi session factory, cada session factory pode ser configurada para acessar um banco de dados diferente do outro.

Veja em detalhes neste artigo:

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14846/Using-NHibernate-with-Multiple-Databases